# How can I make Wordpress posts show my gravatar?

Tags: wordpress

I'm hosting an instance of WP on a commercial server.  It's under development so I am currently the only user and my role is administrator.  I am very new to WP-- this is my first attempt at setting up my own WP site.  I am using a premium theme-- Photography.

I have a Gravatar profile set up.  My Gravatar is G-rated.  When I open my WP site, my Gravatar does not show in the WP toolbar at the top, but when I click the "mystery person" avatar in the toolbar then select My Profile my Gravatar displays on the profile page and my profile from Gravatar appears there.  Nonetheless, I cannot get it to display my Gravatar photo or my Gravatar profile in posts.  My "local" profile displays instead, with the mystery person avatar.

When I click on the Write icon in the toolbar at the top an editing window opens that shows my Gravatar at the top, but the site still displays the mystery person avatar and my "local" profile biography rather than my Gravatar and Gravatar profile.

This is driving me nuts.  I have literally spent DAYS trying to fix this, to no avail.  I have tried checking the Avatar menu box that says "Disable Gravatar and use only local avatars" but my local avatar doesn't display either.  The mystery person is always displayed at the bottom of my posts.  If anyone can suggest a different means to post an avatar pic beside my bio I would really appreciate it!  I do not anticipate that anyone other than me will ever post on this instance of WP.  Thank you in advance if you can offer help!

Best,
--Mike C.

Comment: Were you able to solve this annoying problem? I'm facing it right now